# Unique Seed based on values & order on a set of Parameters

Tags: c#, algorithm, hashcode, random-seed

I have to generate a unique "Hash" based upon an array of parameters. So far I've been using string builder to generate a unique string for every set of parameters, and then using `GetHashCode()` for a unique int.

```
public static int SeedByParameters(params int[] parameters)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        //Append a character, generated by our parameter, to our unique string
        builder.Append((char) (parameter % 65535));
    }

    return builder.GetHashCode();
}
```

This has worked for a long time but has now shown to be quite a major performance bottleneck, even with as few calls as a thousand. The order of the parameters must also affect the resulting seed. In other words; calling `SeedByParameters(a, b)` should not give the same seed as `SeedByParameters(b, a)`. How could
I achieve a similar functionality with a mathematical algorithm instead of using this string hack?

Comment: Assuming you do not need a cryptographic hash level of security, then the [FNV hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function) is fast, easy to code and provides a range of output hash sizes. A larger output size will reduce the chances of a hash collision.

Comment: To avoid SeedByParameters(a, b) == SeedByParameters(b, a) simply multiply each parameter with its position in the parameter-list. e.g. `(a*1+b*2)&FFFF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that there's no such thing as a "unique" hash code. In particular, if you're using a 32 bit hash code and there are more than 2^32 possible combinations of the data for which you're generating the hash code there are guaranteed to be collisions.

Secondly, `StringBuilder.GetHashCode()` doesn't do what you think. It does NOT use its contents to generate the hash code, [as demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oKowFk).

A reasonably performant way to generate a hash code for multiple ints is using the [`HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-7.0) struct like so:

```
public static int SeedByParameters(params int[] array)
{
    var hash = new HashCode();

    foreach (var n in array)
    {
        hash.Add(n);
    }

    return hash.ToHashCode();
}
```

Note that this is only available for .NET Core 2.1 or later.